# Show/hide content with specific class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'am new to jquery and maybe this is a stupid question but I have searched for an answer just about everywhere without finding one. So, here we go:

I want to show different content depending on what option I select in a drop down form. As I have learnt here on StackOverflow, you ca use the change function to do this:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myselector').change(function(){
  $('.statecontent').hide();
  $('#' + $(this).val()).show();    
});
});

</script>

 <select id="myselector">
 <option value="state1"></option><br />
 <option value="state2"></option><br />
 <option value="state3"></option><br />
 </select>

<div id="state1" class="statecontent">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br     />
<div id="state2" class="statecontent">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div id="state3" class="statecontent">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
```

This code will alove me to show content thats inside the different divs depending on what 'state' I choose in the drop down. But how do I connect the values of the drop down to a specific class instead of an id. The problem is of course that I want to show several divs that share a common class when i select a state in the drop down.

I would very much appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Paul

Comment: You shouldn't have `<br />` tags within a `<select>`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use class instead of Id like this

```
<div class="statecontent state1">State1 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state1">State1 Specific Page2 Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state2">State2 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
<div class="statecontent state3">State3 Specific Page Content Goes here</div><br />
```

and your JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myselector').change(function() {
        $('.statecontent').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hovewer, I'm trying exaktly this code but nothing happens when I choose different options in the drop down. Could you show me the code for the drop down as well, maybe this i where I do something wrong /Paul

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was the link to the library that was giving me trouble!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.classname')
```

selects a class, so -

```
$('.' + $(this).val()).show();
```

would work if the value in your drop down corresponded to a class name.

Answer (score 1):

Read a [jQuery doc about selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). `$("#someId")` selects the element havig `someId` as id. `$(".someClass")` selects the elements having `someClass` as class. It uses the CSS3 notation. That's the heart of jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $(".col-md-12").load(function () {
        $("module").removeClass("hidden");
    });
```

Comment: Chandu Right, welcome to stackoverflow. your answer can be a lot more useful if you can provide some explanation in addition to the code snippet. please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: the OP wanted to be able to show or hide.  This only shows.  I would suggest the jquery hide(), show(), and toggle() methods instead of this.