# jquery selector inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a template that renders a ***list*** of items :

```
 <article class=" product-premium " data-id = "{ID}">
 <h4 class="inactive-subscription">{PRICE}</h4>
 <h4 class="active-subscription">Active subscription</h4>
```

I check on subscriptions , if the status of the subscription === active then I want to hide an h4 tag with inactive class  and vice versa.

```
  let subscriptions = //fetching from some api
  let $productsCard = $('.premium-product') // the attrbute I want to select in order to compare subscriptions ids to it  
  let productId = $productsCard.data('id')
  if (subscriptions && subscriptions.length) {
    subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
    $productsCard.forEach((productCard) => {
      if (subscription.id === productId) {
        if (subscription.status === 'ACTIVE') {
          $('.inactive-subscription').hide()
        } else {
          $('.active-subscription').hide()
        }
      }
      }
    })
  }
```

But it is not working since the H4 tags I want to hide are still visible

Comment: are inactive-subscription & active-subscription classes or id?

Comment: Also need to see your HTML

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide content with specific class using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865964/show-hide-content-with-specific-class-using-jquery)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].
I think your selector is not working fine.

Comment: `subscriptions = //fetching from some api` - are you fetching these asynchronously?  Might be that your code is running before `subscriptions` has been populated.

Comment: `$('.js-premium-product')` and `article class="product-premium"` - these class names don't match

Comment: Following your edit: `$('.premium-product')` and article `class="product-premium"` - these class names *still* don't match

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information, html is needed and where (on which Element) are the classes set.
The scope of the hide funtion is wrong, too, should be

```
$(productCard).find('.inactive-subscription').hide()
```

or

```
$(productCard).find('.active-subscription').hide()
```

else You always hide all tags on your page.

Answer (score 0):

In your html you are using **product-premium** as class

```
  <article class=" product-premium " data-id = "{ID}">
```

But you are selecting it with **premium-product** in your script

```
let $productsCard = $('.premium-product')
```

jQuery **find** method will solve the problem

Example:

```
jQuery($productsCard).find('.active-subscription').hide()
```

Thanks